# Cannot find UnityEngine.InputSystem

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a new unity project and to be honest i am new at this.
I need to use the InputSystem package but Visual studio does not recognize it.

This is the version of my VS. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.3 and the version of Unity is 2020.2.1

As you can see by the picture, my VS already knows that I am working in a Unity project.
[image]

So the first thing that I tried doing is to regenerate project files but it didnt work. I also selected my VS as my default external script editor.
This is my external tools.
[image]

I re-installed VS using unity hub but nothing happend.

Do you have any suggestions? I followed some tutorials I saw over the internet but I am still getting no positive results and to be honest, I am getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just tested out the package installation. I installed the package in a fresh, empty Unity project. Here are the steps that I went through which worked in my case:

1. Locate the `Input System` package in the Package Manager
2. Click install
3. A warning prompt will appear, click yes
4. Unity Editor should now get re-launched on it's own, wait for that to happen
5. If Visual Studio is open, close it
6. Open Visual studio - right click on the `Assets` folder and select `Open C# project`
7. `UnityEngine.InputSystem` namespace should now be available, if not, re-open Visual Studio one more time

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. By package manager do you mean the unity one or the one in VS? I couldn't find it in either of them. I am probably doing something wrong

Comment: ok ok, so now I found it installed in my package manager of unity. I had to clic where it says unity registry. I installed it and it worked. Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Steps 5 & 6 were key for me. Everything else had already been done, but VS2019 couldn't see all the packages, I guess. Closing it and selecting Open C# project on the Assets folder took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me works when I install .NET and .NET Core and reboot the computer. (made this on Windows)

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1